# Moving a camera from it's current position to a specific position smoothly in unity?

Tags: c#, camera, interpolation, unity-game-engine

I  have a camera that is orbited, panned around an object to showcase the object in question, because the object is rather large it's easy to potentially lose your position and want to get back to the starting position, I'd like to do this via a button.

I'd also like this transition to not be jarring, a smooth transition between it's current position and the one specified. I realise this is an interp related question and I've no idea where to start with this.

My basic transform code so far is

```
public Camera MainCamera;

public void UserClickedCameraResetButton()
{
    MainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(106, 68, 15);
    MainCamera.transform.rotation = new Vector4(40, 145, 0);
}
```

As usual many thanks

UPDATED WITH CODE THAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM.

```
public Camera MainCamera;
public GameObject TargetPosition;
public int speed = 2;
bool camera_move_enabled = false;

void Update()
{

    if (camera_move_enabled)
    {
        MainCamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, TargetPosition.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        MainCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, TargetPosition.transform.rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}

public void UserClickedCameraResetButton()
{
    TargetPosition.transform.position = new Vector3(-106.2617f, 68.81419f, 14.92558f);
    TargetPosition.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(39.7415f, 145.0724f, 0);
    camera_move_enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, set your transform position and rotation to a targetposition object. since the transition has to be done over multiple frames you have to put this under update method. you can set an variable to enable or disable the camera movement. just change the targetposition and enable the camera movement to move the camera.

```
public GameObject Targetposition;
public bool camera_move_enabled;

void Update () {

  if(camera_move_enabled){
       Maincamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, Targetposition.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
       Maincamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, Targetposition.transform.rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
  }

}

public void UserClickedCameraResetButton()
{
    Targetposition.transform.position = new Vector3(106, 68, 15);
    Targetposition.transform.rotation = new Vector4(40, 145, 0);
    camera_move_enabled = true;
}
```

disable the camera_move_enabled after transition. change the speed value(float) to faster/slower transition.

i'm also new to unity so this may be not the best solution :)

Comment: You can add a bool to check the state of `camera_move_enable`, I need to check what `Targetposition` is all about as that's throwing up some errors at the moment.

Comment: `Targetposition` is a gameobject. Make another camera and make it Targetposition, so you can see how the final camera view look like and make adjustments.

Comment: Got it to work, had to change the `vector4` to a `quaternion.euler` will update OP with working code. Only problem now is the bool to sort out a one click solution, at the moment you have to click and hold and it'll pull the cam back to it's before position.

Comment: Just call the `UserClickedCameraResetButton()` method on mouse click. cant see why it comes back to the starting position.